# php strip_tags issue

Tags: php

i want to strip all the html tags from a string except ( `<img> and <br>` ).

i used strip_tags(); but it stript all the html tags.

regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those need to be specified in the second argument.

```
echo strip_tags($text, '<img><br>');
```

Answer (score 2):

The second optional argument of [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) is allowable tags

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

So you would use the function as `strip_tags($str, "<img><br>")`

Comment: I was having issues by using '<br />'. Everything worked after I changed it to "<br>".

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php, you need to add a second argument, a string, containing the allowed tags.